# requestPermissions(activity, String[], int) is undefined for the type ActivityCompat | Eclipse Project

Tags: android, eclipse, android-appcompat, runtime-permissions

The method `requestPermissions(activity, String[], int)` is undefined for the type ActivityCompat

Trying to add the new `permissions` for `SDK 23` but my code is throwing the above error.

Edit: using this code

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
```

I have imported the following to the activity

```
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

> Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries has both the v4 anf v7 jar
>   files.

I have updated the **Android Support Repository** to the latest 43 within the SDK.

What am I missing ??

Thanks

Comment: Please include the code that causes the error. Like, how do you call the requestPermissions method.

Comment: is it inside `fragment`?

Comment: show your code and errorLog and also the app.gradle file please

Comment: Not in a fragment

Comment: This is in Eclipse ... no gradle file ? right ?

Comment: Its time to move from eclipse to android studio. Using gradle these issues will get resolved much simpler

Answer (score 0):

okay, in case of eclipse try to run your SDK Manager as administrator and then try installing  **Android Support Library** from Extras

Comment: Android Support Library is installed at latest revision, 43.

Comment: Sorry, support library is 23.2.1

Comment: Support Repository is 43

Answer (score 0):

For the method `requestPermissions()` to compile in Eclipse you can simply add `android-support-compat.jar` as taken from https://github.com/dandar3/android-support-compat/tree/28.0.0 to the `libs` folder of your Eclipse project.